# Why does Wikipedia capitalize usernames?

Tags: wikipedia, username

From their [page about username policies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aUsername_policy):

> Wikipedia usernames are case sensitive, but the first letter is always automatically capitalized.

But I've also noticed that, even though I always login by typing "matt" (not actually my username, of course), I can still login, even though they change it to "Matt". So is it really case-sensitive? And why do they do this? I've never seen any other site capitalize the first letter of a username before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usernames are a subset of page titles, and must follow the rules for 
page titles. Mediawiki, the software behind Wikipedia, treats by default all article titles as beginning [with a capital letter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aNaming_conventions_%28capitalization%29) (unless the first character is not a letter).

Note that [`$wgCapitalLinks`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgCapitalLinks) can be used to disable auto-capitalization for page titles. According to this [discussion](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk%3a%24wgCapitalLinks), usernames are always capitalized for compatibility though. (might have changed since then?)

Comment: You're mostly right, but this is just the default. For example Woktionary page names are fully case sensitive.

Answer (score 5):

It's a technical restriction with the MediaWiki software. All page names and page titles [must begin with a capital letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Naming_conventions_(technical_restrictions)#Lowercase_first_letter).

> [Technical restrictions and limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Page_name#Technical_restrictions_and_limitations)
>
> [...] These limitations and restrictions include:
>
> - A pagename can not begin with a lowercase letter (in any alphabet).

Since user pages are subsets of normal pages, they are also affected by this limitation.

When you see a page title, or user page title, with a lower case first letter, they are using the `{{lowercase title}}` [template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Lowercase_title) to force the style.

Answer (score 1):

The first letter of the username on Wikipedia is not case sensitive and is forced upper-case. However, including the code

[`{{lowercase title}}`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3ALowercase_title)

at the top of your user page and talk page displays your username in lowercase.

Also remember to customize your signature on [Special:Preferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences), for example:

```
[[User:Justinacolmena|justinacolmena]] ([[User talk:Justinacolmena|talk]])
```

so that your username is also displayed in all lowercase.